# Linking a Google or Facebook account to a users table

Tags: web

I was just wondering what the general method is for linking a Google or Facebook account to my Users table.

For example, with Google... Do I store the email address/user ID and then just query for that? I know this question is rather simple, but I'd just like to know what other people are doing!

Comment: what language are you using? this could be solved differently in various languages...

Comment: It's not a language dependant question. I was just wondering what you guys are storing in the database haha

Answer (score 0):

you can add facebook name or other in database, and in users page, you can print it and generate a link for these name.
for example, you can get facebook name, and in users table, generate a link like:

```
<a href="http://facebook.com/<?php echo$obj[0]->facebookname;?>">facebook
```